# Renders appearing transparent

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I've been trying to render an image using Eevee, it looks fine from the camera in the viewport.
[image: 3D viewport]

When I go to render the image it appears faded by default in the 'colour and alpha' setting

[image: Render with colour and alpha]

Or when I change it to just 'colour' it appears very dark and the shadows don't work

[image: Render with just colour]

I can't work out how to make the render look like the camera view from the first picture. I've tried looking through the Render properties, output properties and view layer properties settings as well as the model's material properties but haven't found a fix yet.

Blend File:
https://pasteall.org/blend/5d8196baa46c44dea9e0bde429cd2ae5

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (at least a part of it)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: When you change to just _Color_ instead of _Color and Alpha_ it's not actually getting any darker, but since you deactivate the alpha channel there is no more transparent background - which is instead shown in black. And a very transparent object over a black background simply looks dark. And I'm quite sure the shadows "work", too - it's just hard to see when it's all dark. Anyway, as @moonboots said, please share your file because otherwise it's hard to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm new to this, I'll add that in now

Comment: Strange... it renders out just fine on my machine (despite the lack of packed textures).

Comment: Here are the textures in case they are also helpful in working out the problem, I'm still not having any luck with it, I feel like it's probably a problem with the settings for rendering the image somewhere rather than with the model based on what I've seen happen with it so far https://pasteall.org/pic/d976f1196db740f5b30905205c0dcbdc https://pasteall.org/pic/18c62fd5930a412d9f16558c3bf00d25 https://pasteall.org/pic/2006b6de37454c4b9df7e27baf2efaf5

Comment: I just tried it on my laptop instead of my desktop after hearing @ChristopherBennett got it to work and it worked perfectly, I still have no idea what the fix for the problem is but it seems like its a problem with blender on my desktop rather than anything with that specific model